# How to commit offset with ConsumerAwareErrorHandler when using concurrency?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In case of error, ConsumerAwareErrorHandler interface provides reference to the ConsumerRecord and Consumer in handle method. Now after handling the error, we can either commit the offset or ignore. But i am wondering, how it will behave when we are using more than one thread (ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency). If the latest record is error-ed out before the former one due to different cause, and we commit the offset for latest one, but the former one failed with a FATAL error and we should have not committed any offset actually.

I use AckMode.COUNT with combination with !ackOnError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using concurrency, each partition is assigned to a specific consumer/thread so there is no possibility that another thread is processing a record from the same partition.

The partitions are distributed across the threads.

Comment: Yeah, it will be a different thread for each KafkaListener, but the error handler will it  be also different thread?

Comment: Yes; everything is invoked on the same thread, including the error hander; this is necessary because most operations on the kafka-clients `Consumer` object are not thread-safe.